# MY VB 6 not working, had set all compatibilty have done all thing plsss

Tags: vb6

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: VB6.EXE
  Application Version:  6.0.81.76
  Application Timestamp:    3592011f
  Fault Module Name:    VB6.EXE
  Fault Module Version: 6.0.81.76
  Fault Module Timestamp:   3592011f
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000581f1
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 7e3b
  Additional Information 2: 7e3beb1e9ccf6d519c5b994ca59a280f
  Additional Information 3: 7b83
  Additional Information 4: 7b833c57ebcf54809fd3aaccd8ea4f46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is happening when you try to run VB6, try uninstalling and reinstalling VB6. If this is happening when you are running your application under VB6, try creating a new project, manually add the forms and controls (and properties), and then copy and paste your VB6 code from the original project.